# Until successful failure expression that checks for multiple types of exceptions

Tags: mule

In Mule, I'm using an until successful around an HTTP endpoint, to catch connection exceptions/timeouts. I'm catching 3 different Java exceptions:

- java.net.ConnectException
- java.net.SocketTimeoutException
- java.net.SocketException

I want to put the catching of these 3 into a `failureExpression` in my `until-successful` block, however when I try to do something like

- `#[exception-type:XYZ || exception-type:ZYX]`
- `#[exception-type:XYZ] || #[exception-type:ZYX]`

I get an error that it cannot parse these. Is there any way I can specify for the `failureExpression` to check for multiple exception types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted using this:

```
failureExpression="#[exception != null && (exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketException))]"
```

My problem was the `exception` in the failure expression could be `null`, so I had to perform a null check.

Comment: Accept an answer, so that the question shows as completed with an answer.

Comment: I will, it won't let me accept my own answer until 24 hours after I have submitted my answer. Tomorrow I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct MEL syntax. It should be something like `#[exception is Type1 || exception is Typ2]`.

See:

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL
- http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Operators

Comment: I tried this, I'm looking to use the `exception.causedBy()` as it will root through the exception stack trace and match my time.