# Mule collection splitter asynchronus flow

Tags: mule

I had used for loop for a db data to upload to cloud, but it is sequential. I was going through the collection splitter [link](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Splitter+Flow+Control+Reference),according to docs given it should process the data asynchronously. Purpose of using is I have huge set of data to be uploaded, collection splitter with VM helps for me according to the document.

1)Is there any different way of handling this?

2) If I make VM as request/response instead of on-way, is my process going to become sequential instead concurrent as described in the docs:

> There is, however, one key difference: each fraction of the message
>   will be processed simultaneously rather than in sequence. If you
>   deploy your app to a cluster of servers this will have a big effect on
>   performance.

but when it is request/response, it is waiting for the response, when it is waiting for the response is another process starts or it waits to complete earlier thread to finish?

If I make process as one-way and use resequencer and collection aggregator as described in the document, this steps executes before finishing my db status update.
Flow:

```
<flow name="psi2sfdc-VM">
  <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="uploadSfdc" connector-ref="VM" doc:name="UploadSFDC"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
         <when expression="#[flowVars.sfdcId!=null]">        
            <db:update config-ref="PSI_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Processed">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[UPDATE client SET status = 'done' WHERE client_id = #[flowVars.clientId]]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:update>              
          <logger level=INFO, message="Db Update"/>
         </when>
         <otherwise>
             <logger message="else block" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>                
         </otherwise>
     </choice> 
     <resequencer failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Resequencer"/>
     <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
     <logger level=INFO, message="Oncomplete"/>
</flow>
```

Here on completes prints before db update logger message, this is due to async behavior, but collection aggregator should aggregate once all process completes.

Comment: I did not understand the last 2 statements "if I make process as one-way ....", could you elaborate please

Comment: How are you concluding that the resequencer is called even before the update is completed ?

Comment: @Sudarshan, I have tested. Since it is one-way, it will not wait for the response. If I make request-response, it goes in a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your questions.

1) The approach you have mentioned is the most optimum according to me. Splitting a large piece of work into smaller subsets, where each subset can be processed on a different node (potentially), no other pattern mule will get you there. So bingo nice work

2) When VM is request/response it internally does not use a queue, I found that out rather painfully and you could find the story [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849960/roll-back-exception-strategy-for-mule-request-response-vm/30282130#30282130), so that by itself will slow things down compared to one-way.

This bit from your question, I don't fully understand,

> but when it is request/response, it is waiting for the response, when
>   it is waiting for the response is another process starts or it waits
>   to complete earlier thread to finish?

whether or not the next flow (the one with VM inbound) is executed in a new thread, this current thread is still blocked and will not proceed till it gets the response back.

To conclude for your case, you stick with one-way endpoints.

Comment: updated question above. If I config as request-response, is works as async or synchronized way?.

Comment: request-response would be synchronous ... don't see any updates in your question though