# Until-Successful failureExpression condition not working

Tags: mule, mule-component

I created a simple flow which creates a list of names transforms it. The transformer throws an IllegalArgumentException to break the flow. Unfortunately, the failureExpression does not work even though an exception is thrown. It doesn't match any exceptions. I have included the flow and the transformer.

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting    
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core   
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm   
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http    
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">

    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean name="transf" class="com.until.sucessful.tests.StringAppenderTransformer" />
        <spring:bean id="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore" />
    </spring:beans>

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

    <flow name="untilsuccessfultestsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/mytest" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//Names')]" doc:name="Splitter" />
        <until-successful maxRetries="5" millisBetweenRetries="5000" doc:name="Until Successful" objectStore-ref="objectStore" failureExpression="#[exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)]">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="process-vm" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        </until-successful>
        <logger level="INFO" message="After the scoped processor :: #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="processorFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="process-vm" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <logger level="INFO" message="Before component #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
        <transformer ref="transf" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here is my Transformer

```
public class StringAppenderTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

    @Override
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException {
        String payload = (String) src;
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Upon entry in transformer payload is :: " + payload);
        System.out.println("About to return from transformer payload is :: " + payload.split("\\s+"));
        int i = 1;
        for (String args : payload.split("\\s+")) {
            System.out.println("" + i + " " + args);
            i++;
            if (args != null && args.trim().equals("")) {
                results.add(args);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Break the Flow!!!!!!");
            }

        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the expression you are using in failure expression? I guess the expression is wrong ...Please check to use it correct way :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505855/until-successful-failure-expression-that-checks-for-multiple-types-of-exceptions

Comment: The expression is the correct way of checking whether an object is of a certain type. I have this same type expression in other flows and it works, for example this is the same test and it works #[payload is java.util.Map] in one of my flows. If I change the expression to #[exception!=null] for example it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation :
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/until-successful-scope

> failureExpression
>
> Specifies an expression that, when it evaluated to true, determines
>   that the processing of one route was a failure. If no expression is
>   provided, only an exception will be treated as a processing failure.

So 2 options, remove that expression or be sure that the MEL return true. #[exception.causeMatches("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException")]

Comment: I fixed the probelm. I made a mistake as suggested. This is what it should be: #[groovy:exception instanceof java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!! Really appreciated!